# CSS positioning not working in the code editor

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have this simple problem. I want my navigation to stay on top. I know that the codes should be:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

But the problem is,whenever I'm inserting it in the dev mode(where I write the codes), it doesn't change, but in the inspect element, it is working. The question is what am I supposed to use(class name or id or whatever you suggest) so that I can edit the code.[image]

Comment: just give it an `id='nav-bar'` and in your css do `#nav-bar { position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: Read up on CSS specificity, that will probably help you. Also note you are changing an  elements inline style in your screen shot. You need to determine what, if any style are applied to the element from your styles then make sure that you write a more specific selector to target your element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although your question is not fully clear to me, I think this answers your question:

give your nav bar an id in HTML:

```
<div id='nav-bar'></div> <!-- or <navigation> or <header> or whatever -->
```

In CSS

```
#nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well I'd like to say that position is very important when using css, at any rate you can choose a lot of different positions such as fixed that is the one I've chosen for my example, furthermore you have absolute, relative and so on.
For further info check this example and go to http://www.w3schools.com and look for css positioning

```css
p.pos_fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 5px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> IE7 and IE8 supports the fixed value only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>
<p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p>
<p class="pos_fixed">Some positioned text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```